# Run node script like a bin program in command line

Tags: node.js

Can you run a node.js script:

```
node app.js --watch ../worker/storage/work
```

like this?

```
app --watch ../worker/storage/work
```

Comment: I've been wondering about this one for a while...+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add `#!/path/to/your/node` at the first line of your js file.
2. Then run:

   ```
   chmod +x yourFileName
   ```

   to add execute permission to your script.
3. At last run your file like this:

   ```
   ./app.js
   ```

Comment: Just for kicks I removed the `.js` and can now run it as `./app`. `forever start ./app` works as well just as a side note.

Answer (score 2):

One way this could work is by creating an alias in your shell. Edit your `~/.bashrc` file and add the following line:

```
alias app="node app.js"
```

More details on how to create a permanent alias: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414/how-to-create-a-permanent-alias